# Here Maps Android SDK v4 Explore Edition: Map marker visible from certain zoom level

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

In Here Maps Android SDK v4 Explore Edition I don't see a way to add map markers that are visible only from certain zoom level on. Do I overlook something? In Here Maps Android SDK v3 Premium Edition that was achieved quite easy by setting/configuring the minimum zoom level on the marker at it's creation.

I already checked the API of the MapMarker class as well as the MapView und MapScene but found nothing regarding the dependence of the visibility of the map objects and the current zoom level of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available with HERE SDK 4.13.4, released 2nd of March 2023. There map marker type has property visibilityRange to set the visibility per zoomlevel range.

See the docs online here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.13.4.0/api_reference/com/here/sdk/mapview/MapMarker.html#setVisibilityRanges(java.util.List)